# Replace ID tags so they can be used more often

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the best way to solve this problem? I want the 2nd gives the same "effect" as the 1st.

```js
$("#flip").click(function() {
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

```css
#panel {
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     display: none;
    }

    #flip {
    text-decoration: underline
    }
```

```html
<div id="flip">+ Test 1</div>
    <div id="panel">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, purus imperdiet tincidunt pretium, sem elit auctor nisl, nec viverra quam lacus dignissim risus.
    </div>

    <div id="flip">+ Test 2</div>
    <div id="panel">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, purus imperdiet tincidunt pretium, sem elit auctor nisl, nec viverra quam lacus dignissim risus.
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I know it is on the IDs and I can use them only once but I don't know how to solve it.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Like you said an ID can only be used once. Use a class instead. If you share code we can help even more.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mj1gpsky/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mj1gpsky/2/

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(e){
   
      $('#' + $(this).data("open")).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.flip {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="flip" data-open="panel1">+ Test 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="panel1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, purus imperdiet tincidunt pretium, sem elit auctor nisl, nec viverra quam lacus dignissim risus.</div>
    
    <div class="flip" data-open="panel2">+ Test 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="panel2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum, purus imperdiet tincidunt pretium, sem elit auctor nisl, nec viverra quam lacus dignissim risus.</div>
```

Hope this helps